# What are the best websites/books/ translations of works of Vallabhacharya and Shuddhādvaita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, philosophy, vedanta, bhagavata-purana, vallabhacharya

I want translations of works of Vallabhacharya, and Pushti Maarg such as the Gita bhashya and Bhagwat Purana Bhashya in Hindi/English. Along with that what are the best websites to learn about Rudra Sampradaya?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! "what are the best websites to learn about Rudra Sampradaya" -- best is subjective/opinion based and we don't entertain opinion based Q/A..

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete collection of Vallabhacharya's work with translation;

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/mobile/folders/0B9lkdEaIaFUDfkJ5QmRKM1ZfNlk1YVp2QlRqZldlMHR0TUFQak0zSy0telNob3FwMWoycXM?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-wqfQLzQA4i4xk8zienZYeQ

Answer (score 1):

https://archive.org/details/subodhini_vol_24/mode/2up?view=theater .(only some chapters)

[Here](https://archive.org/details/Srisubodhiniji_anuvaadsahit_part01hindi2/srisubodhiniji_anuvaadsahit_part01%28hindi%29/mode/2up) and [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B9lkdEaIaFUDfkJ5QmRKM1ZfNlk1YVp2QlRqZldlMHR0TUFQak0zSy0telNob3FwMWoycXM?resourcekey=0-wqfQLzQA4i4xk8zienZYeQfrom)
have complete hindi translation of commentary of vallabhacharya on bhagavat purana.

Also [here](https://iskcondesiretree.com/forum/topics/websites-for-all-vaishnava-sampradaya) you will find websites for all vaishnav sampradayas

Comment: Is there Eng translation?

Comment: I have no idea, if i will get it , i will surely post link.

Answer (score 1):

Here are websites for their respective topic you asked for:
https://www.drikpanchang.com/astrology/prediction/mesha-rashi/mesha-rashi-daily-rashiphal.html
https://pushtimarg.net/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavata_Purana
These are the hindi and modern english tranlsations of this work, I hope you find this helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).